# Need instructions integrating a wrapbootstrap theme into a new rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I just purchased a theme at wrapbootstrap and fired up a new Rails app to experiment with it. The theme came with no documentation and I am new to Rails, so I could use some help. None of the other examples here are very detailed and there do not seem to be blog posts about this online. Thanks.

This is the theme, if that helps- Presume that I am running Rails 3, have ran 'rails new experiment' and have installed no gems at this point, not even bootstrap at this point. Would love to have definitive instructions for others, from the beginning, here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you know if the theme files include the Bootstrap files or do you need to install Bootstrap separately?

Answer (score 14):

I suggest you do the following:

#### 1. Copy theme assets to `/vendor`

- Copy all CSS files to `vendor/assets/stylesheets`
- Copy all JavaScript files to `vendor/assets/javascripts`
- Copy all images to `vendor/assets/images`

#### 2. Create entries in asset manifests

- Create an entry in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` for each CSS file you wish to include in your application. All the files listed in there should be automatically included into all pages that use the default layout `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.
- Same thing for JavaScripts under `app/assets/javascripts/applications.js`.

#### 3. Separate theme customizations from original theme files

Feel free to customize your theme, but put your own files under `app/assets/stylesheets`, `app/assets/javascripts` and `app/assets/images`. That way they won't get mixed up with the theme you purchased and you can easily delete your changes without fear of mangling your theme.

#### 4. Change image paths

Now you're going to have to manually edit all your stylesheets and JavaScript files looking for the image references. Change all paths to `/assets`. Like so:

```
background-image: url(http://www.example.com/images/bck.png)
```

Becomes:

```
background-image: url('/assets/bck.png')
```

Comment: I should install gem bootstrap-sass as well before doing this? Thank you by the way.

Comment: Please check my comment under your question. Depending on whether the theme has the Bootstrap files included or not, you might need to.

Comment: Thanks - Seems to contain bootstrap 2.2.1 - https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/syndicate-responsive-template-WB0G66334

Comment: In that case, you don't need to install `bootstrap-sass`. In theory at least, just following my instructions **should** do the trick.