# HTML site to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to learn Ruby and Rails. So, I've created a [template site](https://c9.io/kaharo/blogproject/workspace/foundation-4.1.6.custom/index.html) with [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) framework for HTML and CSS. Now, at the begining, I want to add multilanguage platform to this site. I knew about [i18n on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

---

But my question is about:
How to move html site (f.e. mine) to ruby on rails platform? Is it enough to move template  rails project to my site and then merge it? As I understand [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/) support rails platform

Comment: You can move raw HTML into `app/views/... .html.erb` files, and css files into the `app/assets/sylesheets/` folder... but you'll still have to learn rails...

Comment: This answer I posted to another question might be useful in your case. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16630411/1512956